# How do i design my database tables if my objects have irregular lengths

Tags: python, database, web2py

I'm working on a school project wherein I'm designing a web app for cocktails and mixed drinks. I'm building a database of drink recipes but I'm unsure of how to structure the db tables for drink objects with an unequal number of ingredients. I want to create a field for each ingredient in the drink, but that means that some drinks would have 2-3 fields and some would have closer to 7-8. Should I just make a max amount of fields and have certain items with mostly null fields, or is there a more elegant way to do this?

edit: To add a little bit of background about what im trying to do, I want to be able to input a selection of ingredients and return all recipes containing those specific ingredients. i.e. if i have as input (orange juice, vodka, rum, coke) i want to get back (screwdriver, rum & coke)

Comment: No, don't do that. We can probably come up with some suggestions for your design, but we'll need to know more about the data model. Is what you've described all you need? Just the name of the cocktail with a one-many relationship with the ingredients?

Comment: There is a more elegant way. In a relational database you will have a table of drinks and a table of ingredients. Each of these tables has an id column. Then you have a third table of recipes, which contains 3 fields: drink-id, ingredient-id, quantity (or proportion).